# Drive API - create folder in parent folder doesnt work

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to create via Drive API v3 a folder in a parent folder.
But when i run my code, it creates a folder but on  my root and not in my specified parent folder.

Does anyone know the problem?

```
My Code:

    ​    file_metadata = {
            'name': 'GoogleDrive-API',
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
            'parents': '1ZMo8-CcrfSbxJP-F42BXt2Wrdok4UQd2'    
        }
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata).execute()
    
        print('Folder ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify folder id in parents as list

Try this

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': 'GoogleDrive-API',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'parents': ['1ZMo8-CcrfSbxJP-F42BXt2Wrdok4UQd2']    
}
file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```